# Changing the length of a Seekbar in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-seekbar

For some reason my seekbar is very small. I want my seekbar's length to take up at least half of it's parent view's length. Below is my xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SeekBar
        android:rotation="270"
        android:id="@+id/volumeBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10px"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Changing the layout_height to a set value (such as 70dp) doesn't seem to solve the issue. How can I manipulate the length of this seekbar via xml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you have it rotated to be vertical, the width is still how you modify how long the SeekBar is.

For example, with this xml:

```
<SeekBar
    android:rotation="270"
    android:id="@+id/volumeBar"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10px"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Here is the result:

[image]

And with this xml:

```
<SeekBar
    android:rotation="270"
    android:id="@+id/volumeBar"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10px"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great response, I like your formatting. When I change the width, however, my seekbar just dissapears completely. It is still visible in the View preview (in Android Studio), but when I run my app on a device the seekbar is nowhere to be found. Thoughts?

Comment: It seems that any value or the width aside from "wrap_content" makes the seekbar dissappear. Do you think the problem is with the LinearLayout that is a parent to the seekbar? I'm really confused what could be going wrong in such a simple xml layout.

Comment: Unforunately this is not solving the problem. If I change the seekbar width to a hardcoded dp value while the parent view is a linear layout, the bar dissapears completely. If I change the parent view to a relative layout, the seekbar width does not change when I hardcode a dp value. I may need to open a new question for this.